# JQuery affect only "this" element of same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of html elements with same class and a JQuery `click` function when i click on one of these elements, all of the same class are affected by this function.

My question: how can I modify the following code in order to affect only clicked element and not all of the same class.

jquery

```
$('.editorTile').click(function(event){
      $(this).data('type', selectedTile);
      $(this).data('imgx', selectedTile_imgX);
      $(this).data('imgy', selectedTile_imgY);          
});
```

html

```
<div class="level">
    <div class="a editorTile" ...>
    <div class="a editorTile" ...> // affect only this
    <div class="a editorTile" ...>
    <div class="a editorTile" ...> // or this...
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this)` -> `$(event.target)`

Comment: With `this`, only currently clicked element should change.

Comment: your code giving you any error ? looks ok to me

Comment: I added console.log() and when i click one of the elements the same message is repeated several times.

Comment: Of course the `click` is for all. But `this` only means the one `element`. [Check this.](https://jsfiddle.net/pd461vag/)

Comment: oh, so it will still iterate trough other elements even after the current process is done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It already would work the way you have it but it won't be obvious. In this Demo click each line.

`this` points to the *owner* of the function which is in this case the specific  element that happens to be clicked. A more technical term for an element that gets clicked hovered upon, etc. is said to be the *"origin of the event"*. You can also use the `event.target` property which (like `this` but much less confusing) points to the *"origin of events"*. The second example in the Demo shows the use of `event.target`.

### Demo

```js
$('.a').click(function(event){
  $(this).css('background', 'red');
});

$('.b').on('click', function(e) {
  $(e.target).css('font-size','36px');
});
```

```html
<div class="levelA">
    <div class="a">this</div>
    <div class="a">is a</div>
    <div class="a">keyword</div>
    <div class="a">it works!</div>
</div>


<div class="levelB">
    <div class="b">event.target</div>
    <div class="b">is a</div>
    <div class="b">property</div>
    <div class="b">of the Event Object</div>
</div>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: and this should be a comment

Comment: @Mamun it isn't. that is the mystery here. I don't know why OPs code isn't working too

Comment: Well, i just did the same and it only affected clicked element, but why would console.log() be repeated for all elements?

Comment: Wasn't finished answering question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple and easy solution:

```
<div class="level">
   <div class="a editorTile">h</div>
   <div class="a editorTile">g</div>
   <div class="a editorTile">g</div>
   <div class="a editorTile">g</div>
</div>

 $('.editorTile').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
     $(this).text("I am clicked");
   });
 });
```

or you want something else so you can ask.

Answer (score -2):

You will have to generate dynamic class or id to get that particular div as selector.

The other way of solving this would be to use :eq(n) along with selector if you know which div you have to invoke the click.

For example in your case :-

```
<div class="level">
<div class="a editorTile" ...>
<div class="a editorTile" ...> // affect only this
<div class="a editorTile" ...>
<div class="a editorTile" ...> // or this...
```

```
$("div.editorTile:eq(2)") && $("div.editorTile(4)") gives you second and fourth element.
```

For that you have to already know the exact div order

Comment: jQuery does know the exact element without all these specific selectors.